# How to get remote name in pre-commit hook on push

Tags: git, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit.com

How to get the name of the remote when doing `push` or `pre-push` in [pre-commit.com](https://pre-commit.com/)

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution

I used `PRE_COMMIT_REMOTE_NAME` from [pre-push environment variables](https://pre-commit.com/#pre-push) list.

```bash
PRE_COMMIT_FROM_REF
PRE_COMMIT_TO_REF
PRE_COMMIT_REMOTE_NAME
PRE_COMMIT_REMOTE_URL
PRE_COMMIT_REMOTE_BRANCH
PRE_COMMIT_LOCAL_BRANCH
```

#### Context

*.pre-commit-config.yaml*

```yaml
...
- repo: local
  hooks:
    - id: git-pre-push
      name: git-pre-push
      entry: bash scripts/git-pre-push.sh
      language: system
      always_run: true
      pass_filenames: false
      stages: [pre-push]
      verbose: true
```

*git-pre-push.sh*

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -Eeuo pipefail

echo "PRE_COMMIT_REMOTE_NAME: $PRE_COMMIT_REMOTE_NAME"
echo "PRE_COMMIT_REMOTE_BRANCH: $PRE_COMMIT_REMOTE_BRANCH"
...
```